# Prove $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(C_n^k)^2}{k+1} = \frac{(2(n+1))!}{2(n+1)^3(n!)^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Wolfram says that
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(C_n^k)^2}{k+1} = \frac{(2(n+1))!}{2(n+1)^3(n!)^2},
$$
but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a combinatorial proof.  First rewrite as
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}^2 = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$$
Now multiply both sides by $n+1$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n+1}{n+1}$$
Now apply absorption:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} = \binom{2n+1}{n+1}$$
Now apply symmetry:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{n-k}\binom{n}{k} = \binom{2n+1}{n} \tag1\label1$$
To prove \eqref{1} combinatorially, count the $n$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,2n+1\}$ by conditioning on the number $k$ of elements from $\{1,\dots,n\}$.  The remaining $n-k$ elements come from the $(n+1)$-set $\{n+1,\dots,2n+1\}$.  This is a special case of [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove

$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(C_n^k)^2}{k+1} = \frac{(2(n+1))!}{2(n+1)^3(n!)^2}.
$$

Note that the RHS is $\frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n+1}{n+1}$, and you can rewrite LHS using $\binom{n}{k} = [x^n] x^k (1+x)^n$ as
$$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_k \frac{1}{k+1} \binom{n}{k}^2 &= [x^n](1+x)^n\sum\limits_k \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^{k}}{k+1} \\
&= [x^{n+1}] (1+x)^n \sum\limits_k \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} \\
&= [x^{n+1}] (1+x)^n \int (1+x)^n dx \\
&= [x^{n+1}] (1+x)^n \frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n+1}{n+1}. \square
\end{align}$$